# Add integers given by 16 bits in two's complement form (long integer addition) given words of only 8 bits

Tags: assembly, integer, hex, addition, twos-complement

I have been struggling with a problem for hours and can't seem to wrap
my mind around this properly.

I'm using a program that's simulates a Computer architecture with 4-bit bytes, 2-byte words, 16 general purpose 2-byte registers, and a fixed
4-byte instruction format. Words align on 2-byte boundaries and instructions on 4-byte boundaries.
Integers are stored in two’s complement format.

Every byte is represented in hexadecimal form, e.g. 0xff = -1, and so on.
So a word is seen as ff, 01, a1, etc in the RAM memory.

I'm trying to add two four-bytes integers in two's complement notation
(long integer addition). That is given an input of two 16-bit words X1;X0; Y1; Y0 outputs a 16-bit word Z1Z0 = X1X0 +
Y1Y0.

I understand that's the integers don't fit in the given range for a word, 
and my thoughts after reading a lot on about long integer addition
is that one should divide it into smaller parts and add "digit" for digit.

Won't there by some problem with the eight bit with only is a signed bit in this case? I must admit that my mind is quite lost at the moment, so hope it's understandable.

Best Regards 
A curious mind

Comment: The nice thing about two's complement is that it will work unless you get an overflow which you should handle.

Comment: There is no problem, if you just do the standard multi-word addition (pretending the numbers are unsigned), it will just work.

Comment: addition does not know twos complement from unsigned, that is the beauty of twos complement.  The only thing relevant to a normal adder is signed overflow vs unsigned overflow, the addition is the same, you just add a signed overflow detection to the adder in case anyone cares to use it.  so twos complement here is irrelevant, you just make a cascading adder if you want or use 16 bit addition for all of it and maybe mask as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice bit about 2's complement is that - for a given word size - the resulting bit pattern ends up the same whether you are treating the numbers as both signed or both unsigned so you can use exactly the same addition algorithm in both cases. The only problem is that when you get to the highest byte, the overflow condition is different for signed versus unsigned numbers.

Thus, if you need to do a two byte additio, you can add the least significant two bytes, then check for an unsigned carry, then add the most significant two bytes (and the carry if any)  and only then do you need to work out if the result is an overflow if the numbers are treated as signed.

If your architecture has a carry flag, it's easy to detect when you need carry. If not, one way of doing the addition is, as you say to break the addition up into shorter chunks. So, if you have an 8 bit adder, you can do two four bit additions detecting carry by, the result of a four bit addition having bit 4 (if the bits are labelled 0 - 7) set.

Another, perhaps better way to detect if carry is needed is to look at the top bits of the individual bytes to add. Assuming an 8 bit adder

- if both top bits are not set (i.e. bit 7 = 0) there is no carry
- if both top bits are set (i.e. bit 7 = 1) there is a carry
- if one top bit is set and one not set, there is a carry if the top bit of the result is not set.

That way, you do not need to break the addition down into two additions.

When you have finished your addition, overflow for an unsigned addition is signaled by the last carry obviously.

Overflow for signed addition is signaled differently. Assuming 16 bit addition:

- if both original numbers were positive (i.e. bit 15 was clear in both cases) and the result is negative (bit 15 is set) then overflow has occurred.
- if both original numbers were negative(i.e. bit 15 was set in both cases) and the result is positive (bit 15 is clear) then overflow has occurred.
- If one number was positive and one was negative (bit 15 is set on one number and clear on the other), it is impossible for signed overflow to occur.

**Edit**

Lots of questions in the comments. Here's my attempt at answering some of them.

> Is it correct to say that the two's complement form is only how my simulated computer "interprets" the integers when showing them or taking in inputs from my assembly code?

For the most part yes. The only special thing is that there is usually a signed overflow flag because signed integers overflow sooner than unsigned integers. For example, if I have the 8-bit pattern `01111111` and I add `00000001`, I get another 8 bit pattern `11111111`. In unsigned arithmetic, this is perfectly fine. I added 1 to 127 to get 128. If I interpret the number as a 8 bit 2's complement number, I added 1 to 127 and got -1. Most processors have an overflow flag separate to the carry flag to indicate when this has happened.

> E.g. say that a negative 8-bit number given in two's complement. Then I don't have to consider the fact that the first bit should be a sign bit, since in my 16 bit integer that I input that 8-bit is a value bit.

All numbers should have the same width when doing arithmetic. If you have a negative 8 bit number and you want to add it to a 16 bit number, you need to extend the 8 bit number to 16 bits, this is done by a sign extend operation. If the sign bit of the 8 bit number is 0, you extend by making the new high 8 bits all zero. If the sign of the 8 bit number is 1, you extend by making the new high 8 bits all 1.

> What do you mean by an unsigned carry?

My terminology was a bit misleading. It's really just the carry.

> If I first load my the first two bytes into register and the other two that should be added to these in another register. Then to be able to check whether or not the addition of the two first bytes gives a carry, I can bit shift the two registers 4 steps to the left and then back 4 steps. After this I can add the two bytes e.g. 02 and 08 and check for any carry? And then the same with a bit different bit shift pattern. And continue like this until the end where I have to check the last carryout and whether or not this will influence the value represented or not

Hmm, not sure what you are describing. Here is an example. Let's say you have an 8 bit adder, a carry flag and a signed overflow flag. You want to add two 8-bit numbers, 100 and 101. i.e.

```
01100100
01100101
--------
11001001
```

Interpreted as an unsigned addition, the result is 201. Interpreted as a signed addition, the answer is apparently -55 which is clearly wrong. There has been a signed overflow.

Let's try another one

```
  11111111
  00000001
----------
1 00000000
^-carry
```

Interpreted as an unsigned addition, this is 255 + 1 = 256 but 256 is too big to go into 8 bits hence the carry flag is set. Interpreted as a signed addition, this is -1 + 1 = 0 which is correct. There is no signed overflow.

Comment: 1st §: As I understood it, it doesn't matter whether or not the 8 bit integer is represented in two's complement or unsigned when adding since addition results in the same bit pattern regardless. Is it correct to say that the two's complement form is only how my simulated computer "interprets" the integers when showing them or taking in inputs from my assembly code? 

E.g. say that a negative 8-bit number given in two's complement. Then I don't have to consider the fact that the first bit should be a sign bit, since in my 16 bit integer that I input that 8-bit is a value bit.

Comment: 2nd §: If I add the two least significant bytes (8-bits) I check for any carry that should be carried over to the most significant bytes and therefore increasing the value by 16 (since hexadecimal). What do you mean by an unsigned carry? Do mean a carry that doesn't effect the sign of the 16 bit integer? Is there something called a signed carry?

After this I add the carry and the two bytes and look for any carryout here that might affect the answer if it leads to overflow? Since my numbers are represented in two's complement form.

Comment: 3rd §: So if If I first load my the first two bytes into register and the other two that should be added to these in another register. Then to be able to check whether or not the addition of the two first bytes gives a carry, I can bit shift the two registers 4 steps to the left and then back 4 steps. After this I can add the two bytes e.g. 02 and 08 and check for any carry? And then the same with a bit different bit shift pattern. 

And continue like this until the end where I have to check the last carryout and whether or not this will influence the value represented or not.